# Why is mysql inserting a new row instead of updating it?

Tags: php, mysql

My code should be checking the database to see if the custID exists, and if it does, to update the information. It it doesn't, it needs to add the customer information to the database.

Currently, when I use the code I have, each time an order is made on the website, a new custID is added to the database.

These errors are occurring:

- When a new customer orders, a new row is inserted. None of the information
  from the fields is put into the database, just an empty row.
- When a returning customer orders, their information is drawn from the
  database on a previous page, but on this page it inserts a new row and the new fields
  are left blank.

If this isn't enough information or isn't clear, I will gladly offer more code and explanation.

```
//The information is passed through a session object from a previous page.

if (ISSET($_SESSION['fname'])) {
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
$lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
$street = $_SESSION['street'];
$city = $_SESSION['city'];
$state = $_SESSION['state'];
$zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
$safeID = $_SESSION['safeID'];
$custID = $safeID / 507921;
}
include_once("Connection.php");
include_once("header.html");

//check if customer is already in database

$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM bookcustomers 
        where custID = '$custID'";

 $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
     or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
 $sql = "UPDATE bookcustomers
         set fname = '$fname',
            lname = '$lname',
            email = '$email',
            street = '$street',
            city = '$city',
            state = '$state',
            zip = '$zip'
         WHERE custID = '$custID'";


$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
     or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT into bookcustomers (fname,
            lname,
            email,
            street,
            city,
            state,
            zip) 
            VALUES ('$fname',
            '$lname',
            '$email',
            '$street',
            '$city',
            '$state',
            '$zip')";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
     or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

    $custID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
}
```

Comment: then echo the mysqli_num_rows($result) and verify what it return

Comment: It's doing this*.

Edited for niceness.

Comment: It's not if the SELECT query returns no rows.  Sounds like you're assuming the code goes down a particular path.  Check your assumptions.

Comment: My table auto increments custID, so I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[session_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) should be called before your if clause.

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

If you change the top if on your php file

```
session_start();

if (ISSET($_SESSION['fname'])) {
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $street = $_SESSION['street'];
    $city = $_SESSION['city'];
    $state = $_SESSION['state'];
    $zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
    $safeID = $_SESSION['safeID'];
    $custID = $safeID / 507921;
}
include_once("Connection.php");
include_once("header.html");
```

This will resume your session, as long as you created the session correctly and set the fname session variable on the previous page.

If you've set the values correctly and change the if clause to the one above, it should work.

Comment: This was actually a great catch of an error, but I must not have set the values correctly. This did not solve my problem if inserting a new row.

Comment: @McGinger That probably means your session variable is not set. If your session variable is not set, then your select returns 0 results and that's why it is making the insert instead of the update. Check the previous page where you set the session variables and remember to have the session_start at the top of the page before any output to the browser.

Comment: This was it. I assumed I could start a session on the current page but set session variables in a previous page. 3 AM coding...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, moved `session_start();` top of `if (ISSET($_SESSION['fname'])) {` .

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (ISSET($_SESSION['fname'])) {

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $fname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $lname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $street = $_SESSION['street'];
    $city = $_SESSION['city'];
    $state = $_SESSION['state'];
    $zip = $_SESSION['zip'];
    $safeID = $_SESSION['safeID'];
    $custID = $safeID / 507921;
   }
    include_once("Connection.php");
    include_once("header.html");

        //check if customer is already in database

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM bookcustomers 
                where custID = '$custID'";

         $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
             or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
         $sql = "UPDATE bookcustomers
                 set fname = '$fname',
                    lname = '$lname',
                    email = '$email',
                    street = '$street',
                    city = '$city',
                    state = '$state',
                    zip = '$zip'
                 WHERE custID = '$custID'";


        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
             or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
        }
        else {
            $sql = "INSERT into bookcustomers (fname,
                    lname,
                    email,
                    street,
                    city,
                    state,
                    zip) 
                    VALUES ('$fname',
                    '$lname',
                    '$email',
                    '$street',
                    '$city',
                    '$state',
                    '$zip')";

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)
             or die('SQL syntax error: ' . mysqli_error($link));

            $custID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        }   



?>
```

Comment: I did try this, I began getting errors about incorrect integers for custID on row 1